# Generating X.509 Certificates

Tags: x509

I am new to Google API and I an trying to import a users Google contacts to my web-application. In between, there is an error which says :

> Consumer does not have a cert:
>   www.spats.in

It looks like I need something called a X.509 certificate for my server. Any ideas where to get it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okkay....I figured it out myself. I used the cPanel to generate a .crt certificate. I just did it by trial and error and it works now.